# selectonemenu component width adjusting to selectItems values IE10 issue

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Before my application was using primefaces 3.4.2 version at that time selectonemenu component width was not adjusting to selectItems's label text and was fixed according to defined field but after moving to primefaces 5 version all  selectonemenu component width by default now adjusting to selectItems's label text.SelectItems's value has been retrieved from bean and it looks ugly on UI that again and again selectonemenu component changing its width according to selectItems's label value.

```
 <p:outputPanel id="groupId">
<fieldset class="noBorderFieldsetclass">
<legend class="noBorderFiledSetLegendclass">Detail</legend> 
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td colspan="9"><p:spacer height="10"></p:spacer></td>
</tr>               
<tr>
<td styleClass="titlesClass">Title1:</td>
<td colspan="8">
<p:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenuId1" style="width:130px;" value="#{bean.selectOneMenuId1Value}" immediate="true">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="" /> 
    <f:selectItems  value="#{bean.title1List}" var="title1" itemLabel="#{title1.label}" itemValue="#{title1.labelValue}"  />
    <p:ajax update="selectOneMenuId2 selectOneMenuId3 selectOneMenuId4 selectOneMenuId5" listener="#{bean.title1Listener}" process="@this"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td styleClass="titlesClass">Title2:</td>
<td>
<p:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenuId2" style="width: 130px;" value="#{bean.selectOneMenuId2Value}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems  value="#{bean.title2List}" var="title2" itemLabel="#{title2.label}" itemValue="#{title2.labelValue}"  />
    <p:ajax update="selectOneMenuId3 selectOneMenuId4 selectOneMenuId5" listener="#{bean.title2Listener}" process="@this"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
</td>
---
---                 
</tr>
</table>
```

Please let me know how can I make selectonemenu component width fixed and not to adjust according to values of selectItems retrieved from bean.I can't set selectonemenu component width globally because each selectonemenu component width is defined according to screen layout.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your problem, when i set style="width: 100px;" on my selectOneMenu components, the width is fixed and never changes

Comment: are u using primefaces 5 version because in primefaces 5 version selectOneMenu component changing its width on basis of longest options in list i.e select items list.In old version of primefaces this issue was not there

Comment: Yes i'm using primefaces 5, try using firebug to inspect your element and check that the width is rigth and that no other style classes are manipulating the onemenu

Comment: I am using IE browser beacuse our client supports IE browser.In firefox its proper but in IE issue is there

Comment: Ohhh... you should have mentioned that it was an IE problem, thats very important. Which version?